# Construct a formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have these set of data points (x,y):

```
x      y
0      0
1      1
2      2
...   
99     99
100    100
101    110
102    120
...
190    1000
191    1100
192    1200
...
```

I need to find f(x) and the reverse formula f(y) for these set.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find y, 
if x<10 we have y=x.

otherwise
we calculate M=x mod 90

if M>9 then

y=M*10^(x/90)

otherwise,

y=(M+90)*10^(x/90-1)

where / is integer division and ^ is the power operator.

To find x, if y<10 we have x=y.

otherwise we write y as y=AB0...0 
where the number of zeros is C.

Then
x=90*c+AB

where AB is a two digit number=10*A+B

Comment: The formula for f(x) is almost right, the code in c# is:    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
            {
                var M = x % 90;
                int y;
                if (M > 9)
                {
                    y = (int) (M * (Math.Pow(10, x/90)));
                }
                else
                {
                    y = (int) ((M + 90) * (Math.Pow(10, (x/90 - 1))));
                }
                Console.Out.WriteLine("x: {0}, y: {1}", x, y);
            }
            
        }
    }

Comment: the results for f(x) are: x: 1, y: 9
x: 2, y: 9 ... x: 10, y: 10
x: 11, y: 11 .. x: 100, y: 100
x: 101, y: 110
x: 102, y: 120 ... and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the term "function" with "formula". One very important aspect of functions is that they can be *arbitrary*. That is to say, even though you specified loads of data points, that tells you *nothing* about what a function that agrees with those data points does. Only in the presence of some additional requirements such as energy minimisation can you say that your data points might define a function.

As to whether there is some formula that matches your data that is a whole other question. What kind of terms do you expect in your formula? Have you tried [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis)?

Comment: Edited function to Formula. The only term that I expect in the formula is that given an x in the above data set, it will produce the given y. Nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @yinon answer here is the C# code for the suggested formula:

```
namespace testM
{
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    private static int Fx(int x)
    {
        var M = x % 90;
        int y;
        if (x <= 9)
        {
            y = x;
        }
        else if (M > 9)
        {
            y = (int) (M*(Math.Pow(10, x/90)));
        }
        else
        {
            y = (int) ((M + 90)*(Math.Pow(10, (x/90 - 1))));
        }

        return y;
    }

    private static int Fy(int y)
    {
        var fy = y;
        if (y >= 100)
        {
            var numOfZeroes = y.ToString().Substring(2).Count(p => p == '0');
            var AB = int.Parse(y.ToString().Substring(0, 2));
            fy = 90*numOfZeroes + AB;
        }
        return fy;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 742; x++)
        {
            var y = Fx(x);
            var fy = Fy(y);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("x: {0}, y: {1}, f(y): {2}", x, y, fy);
        }
    }
}
}
```